# What uniform is this man wearing in South Wales just before World War 2?

Tags: world-war-two, identification, uniform, 1930s

This picture is from a Swansea Facebook group. It was taken in South Wales just before World War 2. He was thought to be a member of the Coast Guard or Civil Defence.

What uniform is this man wearing?

[image: South Wales prior to World War 2]

Comment: Where did you find this image?

Comment: On a Swansea Facebook group.

Comment: The uniform is very similar to a [British officer's No. 1 (*Temperate Ceremonial*) Dress (1937 version)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniforms_of_the_British_Army#No.1:_Temperate_ceremonial), except that hip pockets (and their polished buttons) are absent from the jacket. The buttons identify this as a "ceremonial" rather than "battle" dress (as expected for a formal photo); but the belt is not red or white The uniform appears to be about the right colour for "*Blues*" - definitely too dark for the army's *olive drab*, possibly too dark also for the RAF. Could it be a Commonwealth uniform?